# How can I `git push` to GitHub on Ubuntu using a single command, without having to type in my email each time?

Tags: linux, git, github

I want to `git push` on Ubuntu via a single command, such as:

```bash
echo -e "email\ntoken" | git push origin branchName

git push origin branchName && email && token
```

But after the command I have to put in my email:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the username once as part of the https git remote address.

First run `git remote -vv` to get the full, current remote URL.

Then to change your existing remote, you can do a command like:

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://yourname@github.com/yourname/yourrepo.git
```

where the new part is `yourname@` (substitute your github user name) and the rest of the URL should be the same as shown in `git remote -vv`

Answer (score 1):

### How to use ssh keys to easily push to / pull from GitHub

You need to:

1. Configure your remote to use the ssh version of the GitHub repo address instead of the http version.
2. Generate a public/private ssh key pair, and add the public key to your GitHub account manually via your web browser.

### Details

1. Configure your remote to use the ssh version of the GitHub repo address instead of the http version. Ex:
   For this repo of mine: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world, use this ssh URL: git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world.git instead of this HTTPS one: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world.git:

   ```bash
   # View your current remote servers and their URLs
   git remote -v

   # Set your `origin` remote server to use the ssh URL instead
   # of the HTTPS one
   git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world.git
   ```
2. Generate a public/private ssh key pair, and add the public key to your GitHub account manually via your web browser.
   See my full notes on ssh stuff here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh

   ```bash
   # generate a public/private ssh key pair
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"

   # Ensure the ssh-agent is running (this starts the `ssh-agent`)
   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

   # Add your private key to it; update the path to your private key below, as
   # required, based on what path you interactively selected above when
   # generating the key
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

   # Verify what keys have been added to the ssh-agent by listing
   # (`-l`) currently-added keys. 
   # A. If you see "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.",
   # it means the `ssh-agent` has not been started yet, so you must start it
   # with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`. 
   # B. If you see "The agent has no identities.", it means the ssh-agent is
   # running but you haven't added any ssh keys to it, so run `ssh-add
   # path/to/private_key` to add a key to the agent.
   ssh-add -l
   ```

   Now log into github in a web browser and click on your profile image --> Settings --> SSH and GPG keys (on left) --> New SSH key --> copy and paste the contents of your .pub key file (ex: run `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` on your Ubuntu machine to read the public key--adjust that path as necessary if you used a different file name) into GitHub here --> click "Add SSH key".

   Now, whenever you type `git push` it automatically works, using your ssh key.

### References

1. My full ssh notes: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh